# Powers Table MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For this question, I'm supposed to create a NxN powers table in matlab using arrays.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
C = [];
D = [];

N = input('Enter the value you would like to use for your NxN Powers Table: ');

for i = 1:N 
    for j = 1:N  
        C = [C;i^j];    
    end  
    C = transpose(C);
    D = [D;C];  
    C = [];
end

D
```

This code works perfectly fine for any numbers from 1-9, as soon as I enter anything greater than that, it prints out weird values.

Here is the output I have using 5 as an input, and the second one is using 10 as an input.

```
Enter the value you would like to use for your NxN Powers Table: 5

D =

       1           1           1           1           1
       2           4           8          16          32
       3           9          27          81         243
       4          16          64         256        1024
       5          25         125         625        3125


Enter the value you would like to use for your NxN Powers Table: 10

D =

  1.0e+010 *

0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0001
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0002    0.0010
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0002    0.0010    0.0060
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0001    0.0006    0.0040    0.0282
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0002    0.0017    0.0134    0.1074
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0001    0.0005    0.0043    0.0387    0.3487
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0001    0.0010    0.0100    0.1000    1.0000
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with my code? Seems like a simple fix, I just can't figure out whats wrong with it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the `1.0e+010 *`. It means that the numbers should be multiplied by 10000000000. Five  digits are not enough to print it. Insert `format long` or `format short g` to see the whole numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Don't know why I didnt think if that before

Answer (score 1):

I think your code works fine. Note that 10^10 = 1e10; the very last element in your output `D` is indeed 1e10. Check individual elements `D(i,j)` to verify that those are correct. MATLAB can't display all the elements because some elements are so much larger than other ones; 1e10 has 10 digits in it, for instance, while 1^1 = 1 has 1 digit. So spacing would get screwed up if this behavior didn't happen.